# Absolute positioning of text on a container - flutter

Tags: flutter, position, flutter-dependencies, absolute, absolutelayout

## I want to absolutely position a text on a container.

```
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      width: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xE5E5EAee), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: Text('Camping'),
    );
```

[This is the present image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmNsO.jpg)
[This is what need to be acheived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vAfL.jpg)

Did tried to position it with the 'align positioned' dependency. But got stuck with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your own example considering there is only one child in the container u can do the following but if u do have additional childrens the best way would be to use a Stack widget and use Align/Positioned widget to position the child widgets as per ur needs

```dart
Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10), // how much space from the bottom
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xE5E5EAee),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          child: Text('Camping'),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Text widget with Align widget and give alignment as the below code

```
 Container(
       height: 150,
       width: 150,
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xE5E5EAee), borderRadius: 
      BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, // ADD THIS
          child: Text('Camping')),
    ),
```

Then give padding as per your need

Comment: This works. With padding on bottom works as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, use a `Stack` and positioned the `Text` with the widget `Positioned` as you need it, `Positioned` has 4 properties for position top, rigth, bottom and left for you to positioned the widget wherever you want.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      width: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xE5E5EAee), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 120,
            left: 48,
            child: Text('Camping'))
          ,
        ],
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

[image: Output result]